# How to hide the <thead> element of the table when no rows match the search input? - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, function

I have a table that contains the list of regular employees, probationary and trainees. The search bar is working and highlights the matched name of the personnel. What I wanted to happen is to remove the `<thead>` element of the table when no results are found under it.

[Here's the sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejD7Z.png)

and also, I want the `<thead>` elements and its elements under it to display again if the user haven't typed anything in the search bar.
Unlike this output:

[I don't want this happening on the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oROay.png)

I reall hope that there's something I can add in my Javascript function so that I wouldn't change too much in my code.

Here's my database structure for database, "multi_login":

[multi_login database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUCFI.png)

---

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:0;padding-bottom: 0;">
          <table class="table-borderless text-center" style="width:90%; height:10%; margin:0 auto; padding:0;">
            <tr>
                        <td style="width:25%;">
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50%;">
                            <div class="nj_searchbar">
                                <i class="material-icons" style="color:#cc0000;font-weight: bold;">search</i>
                                <input type="text" id="search-personnel" onkeyup="searchPerson()" placeholder="Who are you looking for?" >
                                <i class="material-icons clear" style="display: none;color:#cc0000;font-weight: bold;">clear</i>
                                <div id="resultFound">...</div>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:50%;">
                            <button href="#" title="Add Personnel" id="add" class="add-btn-dark btn" style="float:right;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPersonModal"><i class="material-icons icon_dark">group_add</i>&nbsp;Add New Personnel</button>
                        </td>
            </tr>
          </table>


        </div>
<div class="col-sm-12">
            <!-- <button href="#" title="Add Personnel" id="add" class="add-btn-dark btn btn-outline-dark" style="float:right;margin-right:5%;margin-bottom:1%;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editPersonModal"><i class="material-icons icon_dark">group_add</i>&nbsp;Add New Personnel</button> -->
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered text-center personTable" id="personnelTable" style="width:90%; margin:0 auto;padding:0;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);border-radius:50px;">
             <thead class="employeeList">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Employee Name</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Date of Birth</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">TIN</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">SSS Number</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">PhilHealth Number</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Pag-IBIG MID No./RTN</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">ACTIONS</th>
                    </tr>
             </thead>
                <?php display_employee(); ?>
             <thead class="probList">   
                    <tr>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Probationary Name</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Date of Birth</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">TIN</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">SSS Number</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">PhilHealth Number</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Pag-IBIG MID No./RTN</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">ACTIONS</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
                <?php display_probationary(); ?>
                <thead class="trainList">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Trainee Name</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Date of Birth</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">TIN</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">SSS Number</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">PhilHealth Number</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">Pag-IBIG MID No./RTN</th>
                        <th class="theader" style="color:white;">ACTIONS</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <?php display_trainee(); ?>
            </table> 
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.table tr td
{
    font-size:15px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.personTable td:hover
{
    color:#cc0000;
    font-weight: 500;
}

/*background color of headers in table*/
.theader
{
    background-color: black;
}
```

**PHP:**
*functions.php*

```
// connect to database
$userhost = 'root';
$userPass = '';
$dataBase = 'multi_login';
$host = 'localhost';
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', $dataBase);


function display_employee()
{
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_type='Regular' AND emp_status='Active'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    echo "<tbody>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $empMname = $row['emp_mname'];
        $empbdate = $row['emp_bdate'];
        // to display Month and Day only
        $newdate = date('F d', strtotime($empbdate)); 

        // to hide the first 6 numbers for TIN Number
        $empTin = $row['emp_tin'];
        if ($empTin !='')
        {
            $empTin = substr_replace($empTin, "xxxxxx" , 0, 6);
            $newtin = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empTin, 0,3),
                      substr($empTin, 3,3),
                      substr($empTin, 6));
        }
            else if ($empTin =='')
            {
                $newtin = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 7 numbers for SSS Number
        $empSss = $row['emp_sss'];
        if ($empSss !='')
        {
            $empSss = substr_replace($empSss, "xxxxxxx" , 0, 7);
            $newsss = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empSss, 0,2),
                      substr($empSss, 2,7),
                      substr($empSss, 9));
        }
            else if ($empSss =='')
            {
                $newsss = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 9 numbers for PHILHEALTH Number
        $empPhealth = $row['emp_phealth'];
        if ($empPhealth !='')
        {
            $empPhealth = substr_replace($empPhealth, "xxxxxxxxx" , 0, 9);
            $newphealth = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empPhealth, 0,2),
                      substr($empPhealth, 2,9),
                      substr($empPhealth, 11));
        }
            else if ($empPhealth =='')
            {
                $newphealth = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 10 numbers for PAGIBIG Number
        $empPagibig = $row['emp_pagibig'];
        if ($empPagibig !='')
        {
            $empPagibig = substr_replace($empPagibig, "xxxxxxxxxx" , 0, 10);
            $newpagibig = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empPagibig, 0,4),
                      substr($empPagibig, 4,4),
                      substr($empPagibig, 8));
        }
            else if ($empPagibig =='')
            {
                $newpagibig = '';
            }
        //Get the first letter of Middle Name and insert a dot
        if($empMname != '')
        {
            $newMname = substr($empMname, 0,1).".";
        }//if no Middle name, it will only be blank
        else if($empMname == '')
        {
            $newMname = "";
        }



        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['emp_lname'] . ", " . $row['emp_fname'] . " " . $newMname . "</td><td>" . $newdate . "</td><td>" . $newtin . "</td><td>" . $newsss . "</td><td>" . $newphealth . "</td><td>" . $newpagibig . "</td>
            <td>
                <button id=\"$row[emp_id]\" class='btn  btn-sm edit_data' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editPersonModal' title='Edit' name='Edit'><i class='material-icons mIcon' alt='Edit'>edit</i></button>&nbsp;
                <button id=\"$row[emp_id]\" class='btn btn-sm  delete_data' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal' title='Delete' name='Delete'><i class='material-icons mIcon' alt='Delete'>delete</i></button>
            </td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
}

function display_probationary()
{
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_type='Probationary' AND emp_status='Active'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    echo "<tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $empMname = $row['emp_mname'];
        $empbdate = $row['emp_bdate'];
        // to display Month and Day only
        $newdate = date('F d', strtotime($empbdate)); 
        // to hide the first 6 numbers for TIN Number
        $empTin = $row['emp_tin'];
        if ($empTin !='')
        {
            $empTin = substr_replace($empTin, "xxxxxx" , 0, 6);
            $newtin = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empTin, 0,3),
                      substr($empTin, 3,3),
                      substr($empTin, 6));
        }
            else if ($empTin =='')
            {
                $newtin = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 7 numbers for SSS Number
        $empSss = $row['emp_sss'];
        if ($empSss !='')
        {
            $empSss = substr_replace($empSss, "xxxxxxx" , 0, 7);
            $newsss = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empSss, 0,2),
                      substr($empSss, 2,7),
                      substr($empSss, 9));
        }
            else if ($empSss =='')
            {
                $newsss = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 9 numbers for PHILHEALTH Number
        $empPhealth = $row['emp_phealth'];
        if ($empPhealth !='')
        {
            $empPhealth = substr_replace($empPhealth, "xxxxxxxxx" , 0, 9);
            $newphealth = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empPhealth, 0,2),
                      substr($empPhealth, 2,9),
                      substr($empPhealth, 11));
        }
            else if ($empPhealth =='')
            {
                $newphealth = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 10 numbers for PAGIBIG Number
        $empPagibig = $row['emp_pagibig'];
        if ($empPagibig !='')
        {
            $empPagibig = substr_replace($empPagibig, "xxxxxxxxxx" , 0, 10);
            $newpagibig = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empPagibig, 0,4),
                      substr($empPagibig, 4,4),
                      substr($empPagibig, 8));
        }
            else if ($empPagibig =='')
            {
                $newpagibig = '';
            }
        //Get the first letter of Middle Name and insert a dot
        if($empMname != '')
        {
            $newMname = substr($empMname, 0,1).".";
        }//if no Middle name, it will only be blank
        else if($empMname == '')
        {
            $newMname = "";
        }

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['emp_lname'] . ", " . $row['emp_fname'] . " " . $newMname . "</td><td>" . $newdate . "</td><td>" . $newtin . "</td><td>" . $newsss . "</td><td>" . $newphealth . "</td><td>" . $newpagibig . "</td>
        <td>
                <button id=\"$row[emp_id]\" class='btn btn-sm edit_data' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editPersonModal' title='Edit' name='Edit'><i class='material-icons mIcon' alt='Edit'>edit</i></button>&nbsp;
                <button id=\"$row[emp_id]\" class='btn btn-sm delete_data' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal' title='Delete' name='Delete'><i class='material-icons mIcon' alt='Delete'>delete</i></button>
        </td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

function display_trainee()
{
    global $db;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_type='Trainee' AND emp_status='Active'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

    echo "<tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $empMname = $row['emp_mname'];
        $empbdate = $row['emp_bdate'];
        // to display Month and Day only
        $newdate = date('F d', strtotime($empbdate)); 
        // to hide the first 6 numbers for TIN Number
        $empTin = $row['emp_tin'];
        if ($empTin !='')
        {
            $empTin = substr_replace($empTin, "xxxxxx" , 0, 6);
            $newtin = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empTin, 0,3),
                      substr($empTin, 3,3),
                      substr($empTin, 6));
        }
            else if ($empTin =='')
            {
                $newtin = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 7 numbers for SSS Number
        $empSss = $row['emp_sss'];
        if ($empSss !='')
        {
            $empSss = substr_replace($empSss, "xxxxxxx" , 0, 7);
            $newsss = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empSss, 0,2),
                      substr($empSss, 2,7),
                      substr($empSss, 9));
        }
            else if ($empSss =='')
            {
                $newsss = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 9 numbers for PHILHEALTH Number
        $empPhealth = $row['emp_phealth'];
        if ($empPhealth !='')
        {
            $empPhealth = substr_replace($empPhealth, "xxxxxxxxx" , 0, 9);
            $newphealth = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empPhealth, 0,2),
                      substr($empPhealth, 2,9),
                      substr($empPhealth, 11));
        }
            else if ($empPhealth =='')
            {
                $newphealth = '';
            }
        // to hide the first 10 numbers for PAGIBIG Number
        $empPagibig = $row['emp_pagibig'];
        if ($empPagibig !='')
        {
            $empPagibig = substr_replace($empPagibig, "xxxxxxxxxx" , 0, 10);
            $newpagibig = sprintf("%s-%s-%s",
                      substr($empPagibig, 0,4),
                      substr($empPagibig, 4,4),
                      substr($empPagibig, 8));
        }
            else if ($empPagibig =='')
            {
                $newpagibig = '';
            }
        //Get the first letter of Middle Name and insert a dot
        if($empMname != '')
        {
            $newMname = substr($empMname, 0,1).".";
        }//if no Middle name, it will only be blank
        else if($empMname == '')
        {
            $newMname = "";
        }

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['emp_lname'] . ", " . $row['emp_fname'] . " " . $newMname . "</td><td>" . $newdate . "</td><td>" . $newtin . "</td><td>" . $newsss . "</td><td>" . $newphealth . "</td><td>" . $newpagibig . "</td>
        <td>
                <button id=\"$row[emp_id]\" class='btn btn-sm edit_data' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editPersonModal' title='Edit' name='Edit'><i class='material-icons mIcon' alt='Edit'>edit</i></button>&nbsp;
                <button id=\"$row[emp_id]\" class='btn btn-sm delete_data' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#deleteModal' title='Delete' name='Delete'><i class='material-icons mIcon' alt='Delete'>delete</i></button>
        </td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
// function to search personnel on table
        function searchPerson() {

             // Declare variables
              var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue, index, countResult;
              input = document.getElementById("search-personnel");
              filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
              table = document.getElementById("personnelTable");
              tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
              countResult = 0;

              // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
              for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) 
              {
                td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                if (td) 
                {
                  txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;

                  // first clear any previously marked text
                  // this strips out the <mark> tags leaving text (actually all tags)
                  td.innerHTML = txtValue;

                  index = txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter);
                  if (index > -1) 
                  {

                    // using substring with index and filter.length 
                    // nest the matched string inside a <mark> tag
                    td.innerHTML = txtValue.substring(0, index) + "<span class='highlight'>" + txtValue.substring(index, index + filter.length) + "</span>" + txtValue.substring(index + filter.length);

                    tr[i].style.display = "";

                    if(input.value != "")
                    {
                        countResult++;
                    }
                    else if(input.value == "")
                    {
                        countResult = -1;
                    }


                  } 
                  else 
                  {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";

                  }
                }



              } // end of for loop for table rows


                if(countResult > 1)
                {
                     document.getElementById("resultFound").innerHTML = "<span class='nj_have'>" + countResult + " Results Found.. </span>";
                }
                else if(countResult == 1)
                {
                     document.getElementById("resultFound").innerHTML = "<span class='nj_have'>" + countResult + " Result Found.. <span>";
                }
                else if(countResult == 0)
                {
                     document.getElementById("resultFound").innerHTML = "<span class='nj_havent'>PERSONNEL NOT FOUND! Try again...</span>";
                }
                else if(input.value == "" && countResult < 0)
                {
                     document.getElementById("resultFound").innerHTML = "<span>...</span>";
                }

        }
```

Comment: This is why separation of logic and presentation is so important. If your function returned a php variable rather than immediately echoing stuff, you wouldn’t have this problem. You could simply check if the function returns anything, and if so, print it. Also, your functions are doing too much.  All the html stuff should be handled in the view (html page)

Answer (score 2):

I'll be using jQuery, but you can use plain javascript if you want.

First, when the search is empty:

```js
$('.personnelTable').find('thead').removeClass('no-results');
```

Then, before looping through the `tr`s, you add an attribute `data-has-results` to every `thead` with a default value of `0`:

```js
$('.personnelTable').find('thead').attr('data-has-results', 0);
```

Then, for each `tr` that matches the search term:

```js
$(tr[i]).closest('thead').attr('data-has-results', 1);
```

Then, after the loop, you hide the `thead`s without results:

```js
$('.personnelTable').find('thead').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-has-results') == 0) {
      $(this).addClass('no-results');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('no-results');
    }
});
```

And the CSS:

```css
thead.no-results {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check **the number of rows** return from the requested query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num_rows <= 0){ return; }

echo "<tbody>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // You Code here }

echo "<tbody>";
```